# Erro na leitura do arquivo de propriedades em java

Tags: java

Não sei é correto e se funciona, mas realizei uma divisão no projeto. um projeto acessaria o DAO e teria a conexão e um arquivo de properties com as informações de conexão. Outro possui uma classe main na qual não criei frames ainda, apenas uma classe main para teste. Nas bibliotecas adicionei os projetos como referência e fiz o teste mas está dando um erro onde não consegue ler o arquivo properties, poderiam me dizer o que pode ser?

**Descrição do Erro:**

```
jul 27, 2016 9:30:41 AM Conection.GenericConnection getDbProperties
GRAVE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\properties\conf.properties (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at Conection.GenericConnection.getDbProperties(GenericConnection.java:25)
    at Conection.OracleConnection.getConnection(OracleConnection.java:35)
    at Views.mainTeste.main(mainTeste.java:16)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Conection.OracleConnection.getConnection(OracleConnection.java:35)
    at Views.mainTeste.main(mainTeste.java:16)
D:\SICF_Project\SICFCadastros\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1063: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\SICF_Project\SICFCadastros\nbproject\build-impl.xml:804: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 0 segundos)
```

**Classe Mãe GenericConnection**

```
package Conection;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Ulisses Gimenes
 */
public abstract class GenericConnection {

    protected Properties dbProperties;
    protected Connection conn;
    protected Statement st;

    public Properties getDbProperties() {
        if (dbProperties == null) {
            try {
                dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream("src/properties/conf.properties"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GenericConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GenericConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return dbProperties;
    }

    public void setDbProperties(Properties dbProperties) {
        this.dbProperties = dbProperties;
    }

    public Connection getConn() {
        return conn;
    }

    public void setConn(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public Statement getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(Statement st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

    public abstract Connection getConnection();
}
```

**Classe de conexão para o oracle**

```
package Conection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author UlissesGimenes
 */
public class OracleConnection extends GenericConnection {  

    private static OracleConnection connOra;

    public static OracleConnection getConnOra() {
        if(connOra == null){
            connOra = new OracleConnection();
        }
        return connOra;
    }

    public static void setConnOra(OracleConnection connOra) {
        OracleConnection.connOra = connOra;
    }    

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (getConn() != null) {
            return getConn();
        } else {
            try {
                String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + 
                        super.getDbProperties().getProperty("ServerOracle") + 
                        ":" + super.getDbProperties().getProperty("portOracle") + 
                        ":" + super.getDbProperties().getProperty("sidOracle");
                setConn(DriverManager.getConnection(
                        url, 
                        super.getDbProperties().getProperty("userOracle"), 
                        super.getDbProperties().getProperty("passwdOracle")));
                setSt(getConn().createStatement());
                System.out.println("conectado");
                return getConn();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(OracleConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Classe main de teste**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Views;

import Conection.OracleConnection;

/**
 *
 * @author UlissesGimenes
 */
public class mainTeste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OracleConnection.getConnOra().getConnection();
    }
}
```

**Imagem da arvore do projeto**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quando for formatar código, use o atalho `{}` para formatar o código, uma vez que o snippet é para html, javascript ou css. Adicione a imagem diretamente aqui, o link pode não ser acessivel para algumas pessdoas.

Comment: Sim, Obrigado...

Comment: Tinha me esquecido, de um new Properties();, como também não conseguia reconhecer a pasta properties, coloquei ela dentro do projeto que será executado.

Comment: diegofm, Nos comentários, eu posso colocar o link de uma imagem..

Comment: O recomendado é inserir direto na pergunta.

Comment: valeu, Obrigado...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema está em detectar o *path* correto do arquivo .properties no projeto. A questão é que da maneira que você está acessando o arquivo, ele deveria estar no diretório de trabalho, que pode ser acessado desta maneira:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Agora, se você não quiser deixar o arquivo .properties no diretório de trabalho e preferir que ele vá empacotado no projeto, então deverá acessá-lo via **getClass().getResource()** ou **getClass().getResourceAsStream()**.

Comment: Não sei se ficou correto, mas estou tentando implementar uma aplicação de teste em módulos, coloquei o properties dentro do projeto que será aplicação, empacotado como você disse, não sabia deste comando System.getProperty("user.dir"), ele busca dentro do diretorio do usuario, más se tiver mais de um usuário?

Comment: Dê uma olhada na arvore.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B91j9PUXTgJscmpqT3JGWnZ3VDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Eu executei a classe main do projeto Aplication, e conectou no banco pelo projeto DataAcessObj, qual a sua opinião.

Comment: Ulisses, veja, **System.getProperty("user.dir")** não irá te retornar o diretório do usuário, mas, sim, o diretório de trabalho, ou seja, o **diretório em que a aplicação está sendo executada**.

Comment: Valeu, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você está indicado o caminho errado para o arquivo. Não sei se interpretei direito a sua árvore do projeto pois não trabalho com esta IDE mas tente trocar este path:

```
src/properties/conf.properties
```

Por este path:

```
properties/conf.properties
```

É sempre melhor manter este tipo de arquivo de configuração no path root do projeto, assim fica mais fácil de encontrar. Apenas pegue o projeto principal e crie uma pasta dentro dele `properties` e coloque o arquivo lá dentro.

Comment: Eu percebi, ele não reconhecia o arquivo de propriedade, quando chegar em casa vou dar uma analisada, sobre a possibilidade de Colocar na raiz do projeto.. Tenho muito o que aprender... Obrigado